# Android Application not playing MP4 from SD Card

Tags: java, android, media-player, sd-card, mp4

I am trying to get an mp4 playing from the SD Card. This is my second day at it. Yesterday it wouldn't work at all and today is plays the first second of the video before the application crashes with the error: android.view.WindowManager$BadToxenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

I have a playvideo.xml file in the layout folder as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >
<VideoView
   android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in the java code - only a few short lines:

```
path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/videos/video.mp4";
                    Log.i("path", path);

                     setContentView(R.layout.playvideo);
                       VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
                       myVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
                       myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getBaseContext()));
                       myVideoView.requestFocus();
                       myVideoView.start();
```

Like I said, the video plays for a second and then the application crashes.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: For this error we need a complete code of activity. The error is not rised by this code

Comment: post your complete Activity code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getBaseContext()));
```

use

```
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

This should work.

Comment: Hmmm, I know you should not use getBaseContext() but I can't use this because it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);

```
             videoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);//checks when end

             File path = new File(mPath + "/" + mDownloadedFile);

             videoView.setVideoPath(path.getAbsolutePath());
             MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
             mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
             mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

             videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
             videoView.requestFocus();
             videoView.start();
```